# How to add new SBT shell tab in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I want to add one extra sbt shell in the IJ. How to do it?
I want to run some sbt commands inside a two different SBT Shells.

Comment: You can install the latest `scala plugin` for intelliJ. Also, older versions of IntelliJ might not have the same features as the latest. So... upgrade to latest IntelliJ and install latest scala pluging.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Does the latest scala plugin give two or more sbt shell tabs?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I think I misunderstood the question. I thought that OP wanted the new `sbt shall` tab similar terminal. And the sbt-shell tab was not available in older scala plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to run one SBT in the sbt shell and the second in a terminal. You can run a terminal inside of the IDE by using menu View | Tool Windows | Terminal - see [Terminal in the IDEA Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html). When you open a terminal, it is opened with a project directory as a current directory. You type sbt and you have another sbt running for your project.

This second SBT has some limitations compared to a SBT shell:

- you cannot navigate to errors and warnings by clicking on them
- the SBT will not reload when you press Reload SBT in the IDE

Still, depending on what you want, it might provide a working solution.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did like you said. I am testing Akka actors.